# Closing firebase connection

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 python files chained into one file like this:

```
#chained.py
import file1
import file2
import file3
```

Every file in `chained.py` initializes a firebase admin object with the `firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)` method. When I run the three files separately everything works as expected. When I run `chained.py` I get the below error when the second file start running.

```
  File "/home/usern/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/firebase_admin/__init__.py", line 72, in initialize_app
    'The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called '
ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases you only need to call initialize_app() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple apps, pass a second argument to initialize_app() to give each app a unique name.
```

I assume the fix is to close the connection somehow at the end of the script, however I couldn't find a solution yet. Is there any common practice to deal with this issue? Or a method for this purpose.

Comment: Please include your Python script so that the community can assist you in replicating your error. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the firebase app has already been initialized using the below code.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app, storage

FIREBASE_STORAGE_PATH = "firebase_storage_path_here"

if not firebase_admin._apps:
    cred = credentials.Certificate(JSON_FILE)
    initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': FIREBASE_STORAGE_PATH})
```